# Issue with CopyIntoItems (SPServices) - only copy certain fields?

Tags: 2010, web-services, spservices, copy-and-paste

I am using SPServices's implementation of  CopyIntoItems the following way:

```
  $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetItem",
            Url: itemurl,
            async: false,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                itemstream = $(xData.responseXML).find("Stream").text();
                       console.log(itemstream);
                itemfields = "";
                $(xData.responseXML).find("FieldInformation").each(function(){
                    itemfields+=$(this).get(0).xml;
                });

            }
        });
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "CopyIntoItems",
            SourceUrl: itemurl,
            async: false,
            DestinationUrls: [dst],
            Stream: itemstream,
            Fields:itemfields,
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                var error = $(xData.responseXML).find("CopyResult").first().attr("ErrorCode");
                       console.log(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

This works as it should, but even if I take off the "Fields:itemfields,", it copies every property over into the new location. This is great, however, I would like to filter to only include certain fields on copy. I was doing that by having something like:

```
 $(xData.responseText).find("FieldInformationn").not("[DisplayName='UnwantedColumn']").each(function()
```

Answer (score 1):

Copy does just that, does a one for one copy from the source to the destination. After the copy succeeds, I'd  make another SPServices call using UpdateListItems to blank out the fields you don't need populated.

Comment: This is what I considered doing, but we have a few workflows which run on create and would more than likely conflict with this service. One even changes the name of the file (___.docx).  Also, if this is the case (specifying fields is unnecessary), what purpose does the "Fields" option have: http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Copy

Comment: Marc just wrapped what the web service needs.

Comment: Ah..okay. A little depressing ;__;. I'm still curious as to why anyone would even bother using it and selecting the FieldInformation  when it isn't necessary.